# Get itemID from a SharePoint list

Tags: 2013, list, id

I see tons of questions & answers referring to list item IDs but I don't see how to get the actual ID of an item with C#.

I am on SharePoint 2013 and I need to get a list item ID so I can update its content. I have the name of the field. I wish there was a GetItemByName() function. :)

thanks!

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://somesite/sites/itservices/teams/myteam/");
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");

            ListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(TheIDINeedToFind);
```

Comment: did you try the SP API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to retrieve items using any criteria other than the ID, then you need to do a [CAML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/introduction-to-collaborative-application-markup-language-caml) query to search for it.   Here is a sample approach to finding an item by its Title:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://somesite/sites/itservices/teams/myteam/");
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
string camlQuery = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>Title of the Item you are Looking For</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
query.ViewXml = camlQuery;
var queryItems = list.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(listItems);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

ListItem foundItem = queryItems[0];
```

Note that nothing else is guaranteed to be unique.  The ID is always a unique number in the List, but Title or some other field could have multiple items in the list with the same value.  If you are not absolutely sure that only one item has that Title, then you may need to loop through your results to find the item, or make your CAML more complex to filter on more than one Field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute your query
check this

```
            string siteUrl = "your url";
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            Web site = clientContext.Web;
            List targetList = site.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");    
            ListItem targetListItem = targetList.GetItemById(4);
            clientContext.Load(targetListItem, item => item["Title"]);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for a way to retrieve an item when the itemId is unknown, thus GetItemById is not going to help.

Comment: you can use CAML query to retrieve anything or all list items.             CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
            ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

Comment: Exactly, that's what should have been posted.

Comment: i hope i solved your issue